# Texturing is not rendering in blender internal

Tags: texturing, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a question about the rendered image.
No matter what I do like changing the mapping into UV Maps, the texture of a material (Using image as texture), the color won't change like what I wanted. It can be shown using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> (textured solid) but with the blender rendering, it won't show the color. Just white and all.
If I choose OpenGL render image, then the texture is shown (colorful). Can anyone help me? Using OpenGL render Using Blender Render.

Here is the file if you are interested:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you are using Blender render, but your file is set to Cycles render. Your Node tree is wrong, not using the texture image and plugging a Normal coordinate from Texture Coordinate node to Normal of Diffuse shader node.

I added a frame to show yours and then corrected it by using a texture Coordinate node to plug the UV coordinate to the Image Texture node mentioning my own image(yours was not packed into file before upload) and then that Image texture is plugged into the Color socket of the Diffuse shader node.

If you want to use Blender Render then you will need to turn off 'Use Nodes' and add the image through the Properties editor texture panel.
[image]

Comment: hey maybe you should look at this file. it worked in cycles??? maybe you should look at it

[<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2469" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2469/)

Comment: It doesn't work because you aren't packing your textures into the file before uploading it. Probably does work on your end now since your node tree has been changed to look like mine. If your issue is fixed, mark the thread as solved.